# Sequence contains no elements while i have elements

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have in my view :

```
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

         <tr rowid="@item.SupplyPoints.First().SupplyPointId" >
         ...
     }
```

But I get a "Sequence contains no elements" error message.
How is that possible, as if my list was empty i don't go in the @if ?
I've also checked in the controller, my list have  elements...
What can i do?
Thx

Comment: `Model.Count()` and `item.SupplyPoints` seem unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is coming from `First()`. One of your `item`s don't have anything in its `SupplyPoints` collection.

`First()` will throw an exception when the collection is empty.

[Enumerable.First Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)